How could you get road vehicles down into the London Underground network?
For my current project, I'm playing with various options for living spaces underground, where a section of society is being kept safe from harm above within the London Underground network. I wrote a scene where my protagonist essentially lives in an old van/campervan, which is for all intents and purposes a static home.
I'd had the idea early on, but not long after I also rewatched Romero's Day of the Dead in a cinema screening, and getting very similar vibes from the caravan setup used in the bunker, really want to give things a sort of homey making-the-best-of-it scrapyard feel!
I want to make this work - but is it realistic? Never mind all the other logistics of underground survival, but during efforts to move a large portion of people underground, could vehicles have been driven down there via access points of any kind? I've tried a little research so far, but the various underground networks are all a little different, I think the cut-and-cover way the network was built allows some access from overground stations etc., and obviously the trains have to get down there, but I don't know if I'm reaching?

Wikipedia tells me that 55% of the London undergrounds' rails are not underground. It should be called the London somewhat underground... So I expect your survivor found a rail entrance and just drove in.

How do you get trains there? you don't think they're built in situ do you? or that the underground was built around them? the underground has substantial links exiting and entering the underground network to the rest of the rail system, just put your cars on the tracks leading into it and drive them in the same as they do with the trains.

May Glarnak save us from the "as realistic as possible" craze. Along with @sdfgeoff's idea, you could (a) dismantle the vehicle, (b) use mopeds attached to wagon/rickshaws (which would be cooler, IMO), (c) use small vehicles sleeping at best one... This doesn't sound like a worldbuilding question and the [help/on-topic] discourages brainstorming because "opinion based" and "too story-based" are reasons to close questions. And you make a good point about the trains....

I have no idea about the London Underground, sorry. I do know a little bit about the Bucharest Metro, where the underground network is accessible from the upground railway network. But there is no way to roll in a road vehicle; and a regular railway car won't fit in the metro tunnels.

The London tube network has older sections with rather limited ventilation. A poor place a cookfire or a petrol-burning engine.

Loads of food for thought thanks! I think it's an ok world building question, as I'm mainly concerned with the practical matter of getting them down here, not opinions as such. I wondered if someone had done work down there and had experience with it, for example.

P.s. I think with the temporary nature of moving the vehicles rather than running them the ventilation thing would be ok, there is an organised effort to move people Underground in one point in my story, and it does have a ventilation system. I was stood on top of part of it during a tour in the disused areas the other month - fascinating stuff in fact!

Re @user535733 's comment. The last steam train in regular service on the Underground ran in 1971. I think a few petrol engines would be fine.

Maybe this can help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:London_Underground_depots At those deposits the trains are "parked" You can probably also examine the overground tracks on Google Earth for example, but I didn't look for an example.

Depending on the setting, maybe they use locomotives or parts of the trains instead of cars.

@sdfgeoff Just don’t use the Victoria or Waterloo & City lines, which are entirely underground.

@Pelinore I’ve seen cars being added to the Waterloo & City line, and it involved a very large crane to lift them and then lower them from street level to the track. But it’s true that other lines don’t require that.

@Antares yes definitely, I'm 100% going to be using train cars, I just wanted a bit of variance, and enough to cover the population down there :)

@MikeScott exactly - I'm hoping to avoid precisely that requirement. That must have been interesting to see!

A Hi-Rail Conversion

There is a relatively easy and economical way for you to have your caravan run on both roads and rails, and that is with a hi-rail conversion. Essentially it's two sets of small railway wheels set into frames that are attached to the vehicle chassis. Hydraulic pumps raise and lower the wheel sets once you get them aligned to the rails. This is commonly done at grade crossings or in service yards.

Many types of work vehicles have these modifications, often inspection and track repair gangs use them.

(Quora)
Full Conversion

Alternatively, you could literally just take an old bus or caravan, remove the tyres and slap some actual train car wheels on there! You would have to know the gauge of the rails so that you could either lengthen or shorten the axles. This is an easy process.

Make some storage bays to store jacks, tyres and wheels and you'd still be able to run on both rails and roads! Alternatively, you could install the rail wheels permanently (at the appropriate gauge) and of smaller diameter than the tyres. Those would be larger and you would mount them outside the rail wheels.

(Family Garden Trains)
The Unimog

In the UK, and thus specific to this query, Mercedes-Benz Unimogs are a vehicle of choice for conversion into a wide variety of railway work vehicles. As such, they usually carry heavy equipment like cranes or other machinery. The bed portion is highly customisable and could sport just about anything you'd need from a caravan to an armoured vehicle to a transport vehicle.

(SCT Rail)

(SMAR)

This could work, thank you! There is an organised element to the move underground which will include government involvement, so there is enough organisation at play that this could be a thing. Thank you for your answer.

@StrangeGlow: You need to check that the vehicle you have in mind would fit in the tunnels. For example, a regular city bus would definitely not fit in the tunnels of the Bucharest Metro. Underground tunnels are tight.

Yes, that makes sense. In this case I am thinking more 'personal space' sized vehicles - campervans, smaller vans etc, like sprinter size max, for example.

The London Underground owns several self-powered vehicles including two Unimog road-rail vehicles obtained in 1983 and 1986, for use as depot shunters.

@StrangeGlow --- In which case, rail gauge will be very important to pay attention to! Smaller European road vehicles might actually end up being too narrow!

Makes sense! I wonder if there could be a one size fits all system where a service vehicle with such a conversion brings others in. Hmm....

@RichardKirk the unimogs are certainly giving me ideas, thank you :)

@elemtilas: That would be a very small vehicle in the our days. Even a modern (BMW) Mini Clubman or an Opel Corsa has a track width larger than standard railway gauge. To find popular cars with track widths narrower than standard railway gauge you need to go back to the 1970s or before.

@AlexP -- Okay, that's a fair point!
